Django-tenants based multi tenant server is not getting accessed from browser
Recently i have configured multi tenancy architecture in Django using django-tenants package. When accessing the newly created tenants on the Django server deployed on development environment( localhost) it is working fine. But on the production environment when i am accessing the tenants by giving following address:- http://demo.maumodern.co.in/ i am getting following error:-
This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in demo.maumodern.co.in.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
Please help me to diagnose this issue.
Thanks & Regards
Neha Singh
I have tried looking all the configuration on Apache Tomcat and django server but of no avail

There is simply no DNS entry for it, as the error message already indicates.
